# Google mail and moz-box-shadow inside html message

Tags: css, gmail

Anyone knows where i can read about all css params that gmail disallow(filter) inside message?

For example, i have noticed, that moz-box-shadow is not allowed.

Btw about html tags, i guess iframe isn't allowed as well. List of tags would be nice. :)

Comment: I noticed this as well.  Why do they not allow certain css properties?  Box shadow doesn't hurt anyone...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [Campaign Monitor's Guide to CSS support in various e-mail clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). (GMail, 8th column)